# Extracting specific rows by reading the large csv file in chunks and using the same header present in another csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have 2 files, file1.csv and a large csv called master_file.csv. They have several columns and have a common column name called EMP_Code.

file1 example:

| EMP_name | EMP_Code | EMP_dept |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | s283 | abc |
| b | f367 | xyz |
| d | c264 | abc |

master_file.csv example:

```
|EMP_name | EMP_age | EMP_Service | EMP_Code | EMP_dept |
|:------- | :-----: | :---------: |:-------: | :--------|
|a        | 30      | 6           | s283     | abc      |
|b        | 29      | 3           | f367     | xyz      |
|r        | 27      | 1           | g364     | lmn      |
|d        | 45      | 10          | c264     | abc      |
|t        | 50      | 25          | t453     | lmn      |
```

I want to extract similar rows from master_file using all the EMP_Code values in file1. I tried the following code and received the error. I cannot read the complete master csv file as it is around 20gb, has lakhs of rows and running out of memory. I want to read the master_file in chunks and extract the complete rows for each of the EMP_Code present in file1 and save it into new file Employee_full_data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from pandas import DataFrame

df = pd.read_csv(r"file1.csv")
df_items = pd.read_csv(r"master_file.csv", names=['EMP_Code'], iterator=True, chunksize=10000)
article_usage = df.loc[df['EMP_Code'] .isin(df_items['EMP_Code'])]
article_usage.to_csv(r"Employee_full_data.csv")
```

```
    TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
    /tmp/ipykernel_117278/3252874549.py in <module>
          6 df = pd.read_csv(r"file1.csv")
          7 df_items = pd.read_csv(r"master_file.csv", names=['EMP_Code'], iterator=True, chunksize=10000)
    ----> 8 article_usage = df.loc[df['EMP_Code'] .isin(df_items['EMP_Code'])]
          9 article_usage.to_csv(r"Employee_full_data.csv")
  
    TypeError: 'TextFileReader' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the built-in `csv` library for better memory handling. Although it prevents the out-of-memory issue, it might take some time to complete due to using for loop to scan the rows one by one.

Assuming these two sample files:

file1.csv:

```
EMP_name,EMP_Code,EMP_dept
a,s283,abc
b,f367,xyz
d,c264,abc
```

master_file.csv:

```
EMP_name,EMP_age,EMP_Service,EMP_Code,EMP_dept
a,30,6,s283,abc
b,29,3,f367,xyz
r,27,1,g364,lmn
d,45,10,c264,abc
t,50,25,t453,lmn
```

You can use the following code snippet (use the commented line instead of `selected_rows.append(row)` if you want to keep the records of file1 instead of those of master_file):

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv(r"file1.csv")

list_codes = list(df.EMP_Code)
selected_rows = []
with open(r"master_file.csv") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        if row['EMP_Code'] in list_codes:
            selected_rows.append(row)
            # selected_rows.extend(df.loc[df.EMP_Code == row['EMP_Code']].to_dict('records'))

article_usage = pd.DataFrame.from_records(selected_rows)
article_usage.to_csv(r"Employee_full_data.csv", index=False)
```

Employee_full_data.csv:

```
EMP_name,EMP_age,EMP_Service,EMP_Code,EMP_dept
a,30,6,s283,abc
b,29,3,f367,xyz
d,45,10,c264,abc
```

Comment: In the 11th line, we should have a list command before the `df.EMP_code`.  `if row['EMP_Code'] in list(df["EMP_Code"])`

Comment: @msamsami Thank you for your response, But I received an empty cvs file.

Comment: @Shourya I missed `.from_records` in the line second to the last. It should be ok now.

Comment: @msamsami thank you I did try but again I got empty file

Comment: @Shourya I used the input examples you mentioned in your question and mentioned the output of the script, which is not empty (see the edited answer). I'm not sure why you get an empty file.

Comment: @msamsami Thank you very much. I tried several times and if I am trying with different column like EMP_Service it works but returns empty file with EMP_Code not sure what is the problem. The column names are similar.